# SSIS 2012 Lost password for master key

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Is there a way to regenerate the master key that is created when you initially create the SSISDB catalog? I have lost the password and am not able to recover this nor have I backed up the master key.

Comment: I've never tried this, but (out of curiousity) 30 seconds work on Google turned up this which might help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186336.aspx

Comment: Yeah, this is if you have a backup of the key somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alter master key drop encryption by service master key

alter master key regenerate with encryption by password = 'password'

** do it at your own risk,this might change DSK, i didn't try it